# Best approach for saving user data for 10k+ users

Tags: sql, json, xml, database

I need to build an app for Facebook in which I am targeting around 10k users. And I need a data storage technique that would be simple and efficient enough for implementation. How do I decide upon what storage option I need to choose? 
Should I go for a MySQL database? Or an XML approach or JSONs?
Or is there any other storage feature I am unaware of? 
Please help me decide.

Comment: 10 k is a pretty small number in the scheme of things, is the structure of the user data known in advance?

Comment: Guess it depends a lot on the things you want to do with the data after you've saved them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even up to 100k users the data in question would be too little to worry so much over. Over this limit you might want to really think about the method you use.

However, i find postgresql to support more sql features than mysql and be more efficient when handling more data. It is also open source like MySQL and installation packages are available for many platforms. Give it a spin.

Comment: if i have to go the sql way, then why not mysql? is postgresql better? what about sqlite

Comment: SQL is the language that you use to interact with a database, it does not matter which database implementation you use at the backend.

Comment: @amit you might consider accepting an answer, or asking followups.

Answer (score 1):

SQLite can easily accommodate 10k users, with a good amount of traffic.  In addition it is extremely light weight and portable.  Setting up sqlite is a breeze but it is relational so it would require you to give some thought to your database design.  I think using an RDBMS would be better in the long run over using a flat file because it would let you scale your application easier.